# Traits in Scala (Ch. 12, Odersky et al., 2010)

Tags: scala, traits

I am new to Scala. What are the differences (and similarities) between "frog" and "phil" in the following two expressions? What does the second one ("phil") do precisely?

```
scala> val frog = new Frog
frog: Frog = green

scala> val phil: Philosophical = frog
phil: Philosophical = green
```

This example is from Odersky et al. (2010, p. 259); see image below.

[image]

Comment: What, precisely, about the text accompanying this code was unclear and/or caused confusion?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `phil` is just a declaration that restricts you to treating `phil` as a `Philosopher` (i.e. you can only use it in places that expect a `Philosopher` or a supertype of `Philosopher`).  You can do this with a `Frog` as well (thanks to `extends Philosopher`; that the compiler let you declare `phil` is only because a `Frog` is always a `Philosopher`).  So there's no practical purpose to that declaration.

In the context of the book, it just illustrates that you can treat a trait as its own type.  Most notably, this means you can define functions and methods that take and result in objects implementing a particular trait (as well as define collections of objects implementing a particular trait).